# Western General Store - slats and roof

Tags: part-identification, design

I'm interested in making something like the [Western General Store](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/474d637e-3e4f-4472-9d99-4f2a228c7308).  Can anyone explain how they got the slanted windows boards like that?  Also, the roof seems to use some sort of cylindrical T-brick at the apex (in the 2nd picture). Can anyone identify that piece please.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example of how walls have been built. If you look closely on original pictures you can also see [2 x 2 top hinge piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6134) (marked in Yellow here) used for attaching it on the bottom.

[image]

Roof is, however, not connected to the top edge. This is how top edge looks on one side of the roof as it is made out of Technic pieces, mostly:

[image]

Parts are:

- [4623a](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4623a) or [4623b](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4623b) - Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Bar Arm Up (Horizontal Arm 5mm or 6mm)
- [32013](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32013) - Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Angled #1
- [62462](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62462) - Technic, Pin Connector Round 2L with Slot (Pin Joiner Round)
- [2780](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2780) - Technic, Pin with Friction Ridges Lengthwise, Staggered, with or without Center Slots

Each of two roof surfaces are not attached to the top edge as I mentioned, however each cylindrical portion of the roof is attached to studded plates with the help of [Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Light Attachment - Thick Ring](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4081b). Pictures don't tell how these are attached together. Keeping in mind we have plates visible, it shouldn't be hard to create some sort of structure underneath top surface to hold each "plate+cylinder" assembly together.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The slats seem to be 1x4 tiles on a base of overlapping 2x4 plates. It's easier to see from the inside.

[image: outside][image: inside]

The roof T-pieces are **32013** [Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Angled #1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32013) resting on a **4623b** [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Bar Arm Up (Horizontal Arm 5mm)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4623b).

[image: roof]

Are those the pieces you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for all your help folks. I've managed to build a rought prototype of the apex of the roof and I think I understand how the technix connectors work.  Can anyone explain how the 1x1 round lbg rounds are held in place?

Comment: Starting at the top, there's 2 1x1round bricks, then a modified plate (as @Alex showed in red) which is actually attached to the big flat plate, then 4 more 1x1 round bricks (then a 1x1 round plate at the lowest point). It doesn't seem super-sturdy to me, but I think it'll hold. You could always put length-4 rods (lightsaber blades) inside to make it much stronger.

Comment: Thanks rschulz and Alex. I got it mostly put together now.